# Default value for TIMESTAMP column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  my_stamp TIMESTAMP_NTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
)
```

Yields this error:

```
SQL compilation error: Default value data type does not match data type for column MY_STAMP
```

Changing `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` makes the error "go away".
Yet, this command returns successfully:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would also work, I believe.  You just need to cast the output of the function to the same timestamp data type as the my_stamp column:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  my_stamp TIMESTAMP_NTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::TIMESTAMP_NTZ
)
```